# Transferring data to NSMutableArray from NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have a *NSDictionary* that has values from a XML, now I need to put it in a *NSMutableArray* in order to output it in my **UITableView**.

This is the data that I am getting when I parse my xml

```
                    {
            End =                 {
                text = " \n\t\t2016-06-12 01:51:51”;
            };
            Person =                 {
                PersonName =                     {
                    text = "Check”;
                };
                text = "\n\t\t";
            };
            Person2 =                 {
                Person2Name =                     {
                    text = "Try”;
                };
                text = "\n\t\t";
            };
            Start =                 {
                text = "2016-06-12 00:00:00";
            };

            };

        },

                    {
            End =                 {
                text = " \n\t\t2016-06-13 00:59:59";
            };
            Person =                 {
                PersonName =                     {
                    text = “Purpose”;
                };
                text = "\n\t\t";
            };
            Person2 =                 {
                Person2Name =                     {
                    text = “None”;
                };
                text = "\n\t\t";
            };
            Start =                 {
                text = "\n    \t2016-06-13 02:00:00";
            };
```

The size or the length of the data will be *dynamic* How can I store that data into my NSMutableArray so I can output it like this in my UITableView

```
Person    Person2    End         Start
Check     Try        01:51:51    00:00:00
Purpose   None       00:59:59    02:00:00
```

Comment: You don't need to transfer the data; you just need a separate array to use to keep *order*.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i mean. How can i do it?

Comment: It will generally be an array of the dictionary keys.

Comment: Also looks like you screwed-up the XML parsing...

Comment: because of the /n and /t?

Comment: No the `\n` and `\t`.

Comment: I'll fix that issue later on. What do you mean by an array of the dictionary keys? Can you give me a snipper or something

Comment: It's an array that keeps the order of the dictionary elements you want to display in the tableview.  You can re-order this array and the dictionary will be displayed in a different order.

Comment: Got it, but I think i need to fix the parsing first